# have a 2006 chevy silverado 1500 4 wheel drive

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, silverado

have a 2006 chevy silverado 1500 4 wheel drive. last brake job i tried bleeding the calipers instead of pushing the fluid back into master cylinder.First i had no pedal bled the brakes with a power bleeder. Regained some pedal not much. Tried bleeding more gained pedal but now the pressure builds up every time i step on the brakes.so much so it will lock up the brakes as i drive.i can crack the bleeder on one caliper and cad drive a little farther.Any suggestions. Thanks